# How to modify binary search by golden spin?

Tags: c#, algorithm, search

I have a problem with understanding what I should do with this algoritm. The task sound like: In binary search you should modify calculation of mid element by replace it on somethink what should provided by golden spin and this should optimizate your code.

How I can create this?
Below my basic code.

```
    public static int Binary_Search(int[] arr, int l, int r, int search)
    {

        if (r >= l) {
            int mid = l + (r - l) / 2;
            
            if (arr[mid] == search)
                return mid;

            if (arr[mid] > search)
                return Binary_Search(arr, l, mid - 1, search);

            return Binary_Search(arr, mid + 1, r, search);
        }

        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow. Unfortunately, right now your question doesn't appear to make a lot of sense. Could you please give more context on where you got that task?

Comment: I don't know of anything called "golden spin" in the context of algorithms. However, I do know of one thing called ["golden section search"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden-section_search). It's a variation of binary search, not to find a particular element, but to find the maximum of a modal function.

Comment: Thanks for answer. By golden spin I mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden-section_search. I should replace mid calculation on somethink else what conected with this algorithm. I`m so sorry for my don`t understandable question

Comment: Have you read that wikipedia article, or some other material that explains golden section search? Do you understand the differences between binary search and golden section search?

Comment: Okay, in this case can you explain me how golden search work on simple integer array?Just because I'm too stupid for wikipedia explanation

Comment: Do you understand that golden section search and binary search are algorithms to solve two different problems? Can you explain, with your own words, the difference between these two different problems?